# How can I map my Firebase snapshot in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below you can see my Firebase Database structure.

[image]

I do a snapshot like this:

```
func fetchExistingChannels()
{
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("channels").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]
    print(value)
    }
}
```

And then this is my response:-

[image]

How can I assign "channelName" values to string in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
func fetchExistingChannels()
{
    Database.database().reference().child("channels").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let c = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = c.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            self.fetchedChannels.append(dict!["channelName"] as! String)
            print(dict!["channelName"] as! String)
        }
    })
}
```

Try this to be able to get the value `channelName`